# Insert struct in array at specific position

Tags: c

I'm having troubles when adding structs into an array of structs. I have this struct declared in realm.h:

```
extern struct realm_data realms[MAX_REALM];

struct realm_data
{
    int realm_id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
};
```

I try to fill it in realm.c:

```
struct realm_data realms[MAX_REALM];

int do_init_realm(void)
    int i=0;
    MYSQL_RES*   sql_res = 0;
    MYSQL_ROW    sql_row = 0;
    struct realm_data rd;

    while(1) {
        sprintf (tmp_sql, "SELECT `RealmID`, `Realm` FROM `realm_info` ORDER BY `RealmID` LIMIT %d, 1", i);
        if(mysql_query(&mmysql_handle, tmp_sql)) {
            log_fail("realm-loadrealms",mysql_error(&mmysql_handle));
            return 0;
        }
        sql_res = mysql_store_result(&mmysql_handle);
        if (mysql_num_rows(sql_res) > 0) {
            sql_row = mysql_fetch_row(sql_res);
            memset(&rd,0,sizeof(rd));
            rd.realm_id = atoi(sql_row[0]);
            strncpy(rd.name, sql_row[1], NAME_LENGTH);
            memcpy(&realms[i], &rd, sizeof(struct realm_data));
            i++;
        } else
            break;
        mysql_free_result(sql_res);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But when i run, it crashes. What is wrong?

Comment: Which is the offending line ? What's the value of `i` when it crashes ? What is its relation to `MAX_REALM` ? How is `tmp_sql` declared ?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: Ah, sorry! The error is at line: memcpy(&realms[i], &rd, sizeof(struct realm_data));

Comment: Run in a debugger, compare `i` when the crash happens with `MAX_REALM`. My guess is that `i` will be equal or larger than `MAX_REALM`.

Comment: Oh and a tip: Be careful with [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) as it may not always terminate the destination string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, the error happens at this line:

```
memcpy(&realms[i], &rd, sizeof(struct realm_data));
```

MAX_REALM is defined to 50, but in my table i have only 25 rows, so **i** reaches a value of 25 (when I comment the error line).
tmp_sql is char[1000]. I don't get any error on mysql query, if I print results, i get all them.

Comment: How do you determined the value of `i` at the moment of crash?

Comment: I cannot print the value of i at that moment if crashes, but if I comment the wrong line (//) and add printf("%d\n",i); I can see the increment of i. It does from 0 to 25 (i have 26 rows in the mysql table).

Comment: The code snippets you've posted are OK. There must be some mismatch. I'd try to recompile all my files and put following before `memcpy`: `printf("%d %p %p %d\n", i, &realms[i], &rd, sizeof(struct realm_data)); fflush(stdout);`. It must show the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see in the posted code is that `strncpy` does not guarantee null-termination of `rd.name` if `sql_row[1]` has `NAME_LENGTH` or more characters. Change it to `NAME_LENGTH-1` and add `rd.name[NAME_LENGTH-1] = '\0'`. (Actually, your `memset`ing of the struct to all 0 bytes should take care of that last part.)

Comment: Thanks, i have added it to my code, but still crashes. I also have added the debuggind suggested by Marian (printf("%d %p %p %d\n", i, &realms[i], &rd, sizeof(struct realm_data)); fflush(stdout);) before memcpy. It shows the addresses for all the rows, 0 to 25, and 228 for size of the struct. So the memcpy is working... But a few seconds later, it crashes, and if I comment the memcpy line, it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see anything wrong with the posted code. Maybe something's there, but I can't see it.